# how to set spanteks regardless of uppercase/lowercase?

Tags: java, android, textview, uppercase, lowercase

how to set spanteks regardless of uppercase/lowercase?
I have a desire to make input spantext irrespective of uppercase or lowercase

onCreate

```
String s = "aAaAaAa"; 
textview1.setText(s); 
_changeTextinView( "a", Color.RED,textview1);
```

This is my function spantext

```
public void _changeTextinView(final String _target, final int _colour, final TextView _tv) {
  String vString = (String) _tv.getText();
  int startSpan = 0, endSpan = 0;
  Spannable spanRange = new SpannableString(vString);
  while (true) {
    startSpan = vString.indexOf(_target, endSpan);
    ForegroundColorSpan foreColour = new ForegroundColorSpan(_colour);
    // Need a NEW span object every loop, else it just moves the span            
    if (startSpan < 0)
    break;
    endSpan = startSpan + _target.length();
    spanRange.setSpan(foreColour, startSpan, endSpan,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);            
    
  }          
  _tv.setText(spanRange);   }
```

If iam input

```
_changeTextinView( "a", Color.RED,textview1);
```

Textview _tv contain "A" uppercase the color doesn't change, on the contrary "a" the color is change

If iam input

```
_changeTextinView( "A", Color.RED,textview1);
```

Textview _tv contain "a" lowercase the color doesn't change, on the contrary "A" the color is change

I want to set spanteks regardless of uppercase/lowercase

Answer (score 0):

the function "indexOf()" used in the line 5 of the second script is a case_sensitive, probably it is your problem with the uppercase letters, if its possible you can pass only lower case letters in your method, with the funciont .toLowerCase();

like this:

```
textview1.setText(s.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Thanks bro, this is work  , i got inspired